# Animate height of element

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm struggling to get the animation to work when the checkbox is used.

I can only get it to work if I set a height in the css (300px in the example), but I want the height when visible to expand with the content rather hard coded.
It currently does expand but not with an animation (if you remove the 300px), it jumps between heights.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RobertCS/xjkvmspy/8/)

HTML

```
<div class="container py-4">
  <form id="contactForm">
    <div class="form-check mb-3">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="attendance">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">I will be attending</label>
    </div>
    <div class="info-container hidden mb-4">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="emailAddress" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label" for="message">Comment</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" type="text" placeholder="Comment" style="height: 10rem;"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-grid">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.info-container {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 300px;
  transition: 500ms ease;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  transition: 500ms ease;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#attendance', function(e) {
  if ($('#attendance:checked').val() == 1) {
    $(".info-container").removeClass("hidden");
  } else {
    $(".info-container").addClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

Comment: If I understood the problem correctly, you don't want to set the height to some value? I just removed the `height: 300px` in your fiddle and the transition still works smoothly. I am sorry if you are pointing to something else but this question then needs more clarity.

Comment: I should clarify. When you remove the 300px the height jumps between 0px and whatever the other height is instantly, it doesn't expand smoothly. The opacity does fade smoothly which is why it might look correct. Change the animation time to 2-3s and it becomes very clear.